# postgresql return the count of jsonb objects

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I would like to get the count of all products under a certain id.

I tried:

```
SELECT
    count(jsonb_object_keys(data #> '{products}')) as numProducts 
FROM
    appointment_intakes 
WHERE
    appointment_intakes.id = 'VGDKMjdxn'
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

When I run the above without the `count` function, I get a list of keys.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a 100% on this one but I don't believe that is how you use the `select count` in Postgres... Usually it would be something like `Select count(*)`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set-valued function has to be called in FROM clause. Use lateral join:

```
SELECT
    count(keys) as numProducts 
FROM
    appointment_intakes, 
    LATERAL jsonb_object_keys(data #> '{products}') keys
WHERE
    appointment_intakes.id = 'VGDKMjdxn'
```